# Box Mapping on just X & Y Axis

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

I'm box mapping a grunge map to add dirt to the bottom of some assets which works great....except it is projected on the z axis as too.

Is there a simple way toto just project on X & Y that I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe create a new UV map and use it into a UV Map node before this texture?

Comment: Hello :). Just to be sure - you only want the texture projected on vertical faces, but not on the top/bottom faces?

Comment: Not just the vertical faces since that would skip some lower but upward facing edges.

Comment: Are you sure you want to just project in X+Y?  Notice that the beams on your top have some faces pointing in X+Y.  Do you want to limit by direction, or by position?  If position, you need to paint a mask texture to specify where you want the grunge.  If direction, it's doable in nodes (after you explain what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

This is easier/smarter to do with a procedural texture for the dirt, but I got it to work.

- I used Texture Coordinates>Normal>Separate RGB and plugged the Blue into a color ramp to get all the upward faces.
- I mixed that using Mix RGB>Multiply with a Gradient Texture, rotated 90 degrees on the y axis.
- Together, these make a top to bottom gradient mask that ignores only the very top upward faces.

Little more complicated that I wanted, but maybe useful for texture layering.

[image]